# Write Mathematical Equation

Tags: equations, amsmath

Im writing fraction in an equation. But then when I inserted $\frac{1}{2}$ inside the align*, error says missing }.
I don't get it. Removing the code fraction will make my code work.

```
\begin{align*}

 Q(i,j) &= (n-2)d(i,j) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} d(i,k) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} d(j,k)    \\  \newline

  \delta (i,j) & =  $\frac{1}{2}$


\end{align*}
```

Comment: you used an extra backslash right before `\newline`

also, why did you pick `\newline` over `\\`?

Comment: it has double backlash, i don't know why it don't appear. My real problem is why putting this $\frac{1}{2}$ brings error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
\begin{align*}
 Q(i,j) &= (n-2)d(i,j) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} d(i,k) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} d(j,k)    \\  
  \delta (i,j) & =  \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
```

(of course, `amsmath` is called). Please observe that now there are no empty lines inside `align*` environment.

Comment: one other thing you didn't point out explicitly, but is essential: tje `aalign` environment is already math mode, so `$` signs around the `frac` expression are not only not needed, they will result in an error message.